# How to modify .,htaccess to redirect people when they click on link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some website, on it **i want to put link to other external site**:

> http://zzz.com

**When user hovers it - he will see zzz.com** but when he actually clicks the url - htaccess will redirect him to other website

> http://yyy.com

I want to do this with all redirects on the spoken page.

I know its possible to do that in .htaccess but i cant find a way.

Comment: Just  curious what exactly is the use-case for this. Again just curious.

Comment: I guess you have access to zzz.com's .htaccess file ? Anyway you have to implement something on zzz.com server (.htaccess or simple redirect or js...)

Comment: I agree with Nomad101. Why?

Comment: Just made me think of a very simple solution to this problem, and it worked. Makes me worry about security.. But I won't share it, 'cause it's damn hard to find a legitimate use-case for that...

Comment: the use is very simple - i want to cloak affiliate links this way. so i dont want to actually make person go from http://zzz.com to http://yyy.com but i want him to go to http://zzz.com/?aff

im just tryign to avoid url shorteners thsi way and i knwo its possible as i had this code before. would u guys help?

Comment: anybody knows answer? i thought the questio nwas simpler :(